# Why does Gzip compress my css & javascript but not my HTML/php?

Tags: apache, gzip

When I check this website: http://www.tropicbreeze.co.uk/, for example with http://checkgzipcompression.com/ - it reports that it is using Gzip.  But Yslow disagrees.

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/php text/x-php application/php  application/x-php  application/x-httpd-php-source text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xhtml+xml application/javascript application/x-httpd-php
```

Checking in the Net tab of Firebug for headers,  I can see that the various associated .css and .js files on that page have Content-Encoding    gzip appearing as expected - but the php files do not.

Yslow tells me that the homepage is not using Gzip. The Firebug Net tab says that the home page (and other php files on the server) are not being sent with Content-Encoding    gzip

I've tried adding all the mimetype filters I could find suggested, and so far as I can see, DEFLATE text/html should cover it anyway, but still no joy.

I have cleared my cache and am not using a proxy.

Can anyone suggest what I've missed?  Why are the php files not being gzipped when the other files are?  Or, if they are being gzipped, why does Firebug /yslow think they aren't?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what the issue might be but perhaps an easy fix would be to try something like...

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|htm|html|js|php|txt|xml)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

...which should setup compression on popular file extensions including PHP.

I personally think this format is much easier for a human to read too. Bonus!

Comment: Sadly, I tried that format, and it has the same problem - everything (css, javascript etc) is gzipped apart from the HTML of the page itself, which is not gzipped.

I take it that you are using that format and it works? It looks like the problem is not my syntax, in that case, but something about the server configuration...

Comment: Yep, that format works for my site.

Is [www.tropicbreeze.co.uk](http://www.tropicbreeze.co.uk/) the site you are having trouble with? If no, can you post a link to the real site? I would like to see the client headers from my browser to see how they are currently set.

Comment: Really sorry, I missed this - yes, that is (one of the) real sites on that server that shows this behaviour.  Everything is reporting in Yslow as gzipped, apart from php/html files, which aren't.  I'm still mystified by this so any hints gratefully received.